# Admin bar still there after I remove it

Tags: admin

So I've tried like three different solutions:

```
    remove_action('init', 'wp_admin_bar_init');
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );

    function remove_admin_bar_css() {
        show_admin_bar( false );
        remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
    }

    add_action('admin_bar_init', 'remove_admin_bar_css');
```

However, the admin bar is still there. I'm a WP beginner. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the admin bar is? Is this it? http://wpmu.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/wordpress-admin-bar.jpg ? The black bar on the top?

I'm sure I am editing the right functions file too, since I just `echo 'hello'`ed and it showed up. However, the black bar on the top (the thing I want to remove) is not disappearing. I am using WP 3.5.2, upgrading from 3.2.1.

Comment: Do you mean in frontend and/or admin? There several question about this on site, please look at them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wish to remove the admin bar, but you can also simply add the following to your style.css file to override the display of the admin bar:

`#wpadminbar {
  display:none;
}`

Comment: this will hide the admin bar, but leave an empty gap at the top of the page.

Comment: `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');` This alone works fine for me. Did you include it in your `functions.php`?

Answer (score 0):

A plugin may help you then:

> - [Admin Bar Disabler](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-bar-disabler)

Answer (score 0):

there is a way...

Add this to your functions.php page:

```
add_action('set_current_user', 'cc_hide_admin_bar');

function cc_hide_admin_bar() {
if (!current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
    show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

What this does, is simply removes the admin bar for anyone that isn't able to edit posts (contributors for example). For anyone else, it is shown...

Hope that helps!